# update content of custom UITableViewCell not working

Tags: iphone

I am creating a custom UITableViewCell as in 
http://www.e-string.com/content/custom-uitableviewcells-interface-builder

all is working fine with no problem. The loading of data is correct, which proved that the linking in IB is correct too.

I am trying to update the content, a UILabel, on the custom cell from another function in the class which take a reference to the table containing the cell and the indexPath. However the label is not being reset the value desired.

My problem is similar to this: [Cannot update Custom UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421763/cannot-update-custom-uitableviewcell) but it does not have a solution :(

I tried calling `[myTable reloadData]` and `[cell reloadInputViews]` but neither worked for me.

Not sure how to do this can any one suggest something?

Cheers
AF

UPDATE:

I found what was going wrong!
In my current code i am receiving the updates that i need to show in the UILabel from another thread, which calls the updating function on the client object directly (i pass reference to it to the second thread), and that is wrong!! 
I have used instead [myClientObject performSelectorOnMainThread:myUpdatingFunction waitUntilDone:NO] and it all worded as charm...

Thanks for the help and sorry for not posting the code...

Comment: the tremendous amount of code you've posted looks correct at first sight. And I reformatted it for you, too. [self setSarcasm:NO]

Comment: POST YOUR CODE! How are we supposed to help you if we don't know what you're doing? Your question basically reads "my iphone app dosen't work... why?"

Comment: The initial loading of the data doesn't prove the IB linking is OK - all it proves is that your UITableView has got a dataSource. It doesn't prove any of the other two links you are likely to need.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help... i have updated the post with the solution to explain what was happening in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
[cell setNeedsDisplay];
```

or:

```
[cell.custumLabel setNeedsDisplay];
```

that forcing the cell/label to draw himself again

good luck

Comment: thanks for the answer. It makes a lot of sense, that the check for it :) But it still did not solve my problem..i did further test and it seems that non of the labels in any pars of my app is being updated!!! not only the one in the custom cell... it is very weird as it was working before brilliantly...

Comment: The problem was with multi threading. have a look at my update in the post.

Comment: because it makes alot of sense! views might need to refresh manually if they do not update through the underlying framework and i forgot about this method so i accepted your answer as a potential solution :)